# como puedo agregar php a una calculadora echa con javascript para que pueda arrojar un mensaje

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hola solo deseo implementarle el php, necesito que en el momento de que me de la respuesta salga un dialogo mostrando= mensaje: "Realizar los operadores de la calculadora", servidor, operación, resultado, que el php pueda tomar ese resultado que arroja el js y de un mensaje en especial, muchas gracias...

Es solo académico solo necesito conectar el php para que pueda arrojarme ese mensaje sin recargar o salir otra pagina quedo atento a sugerencias gracias.

llevo días intentando conectar el php y no lo he logrado y no quiero desistir....

```js
const display = document.querySelector("#display");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

buttons.forEach((item) => {
  item.onclick = () => {
    if (item.id == "clear") {
      display.innerText = "";
    } else if (item.id == "backspace") {
      let string = display.innerText.toString();
      display.innerText = string.substr(0, string.length - 1);
    } else if (display.innerText != "" && item.id == "equal") {
      display.innerText = eval(display.innerText);
    } else if (display.innerText == "" && item.id == "equal") {
      display.innerText = "Empty!";
      setTimeout(() => (display.innerText = ""), 2000);
    } else {
      display.innerText += item.id;
    }
  };
});

const themeToggleBtn = document.querySelector(".theme-toggler");
const calculator = document.querySelector(".calculator");
const toggleIcon = document.querySelector(".toggler-icon");
let isDark = true;
themeToggleBtn.onclick = () => {
  calculator.classList.toggle("dark");
  themeToggleBtn.classList.toggle("active");
  isDark = !isDark;

  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
};
```

```css
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    $_DATA = ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
                ? json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true)
                : (array) ["num1"=> 0 , "num2" => 0, "operador" => null];

    print_r(json_encode((object) [
        "Mensaje" => (string) "Realizar los operadores de la calculadora",
        "Servidor" => $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"],
        "Operacion" => "el resultado de la $operador es: $display",
        "Resultado" => $display
    ], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_HEX_TAG))

?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Operadores_PHP_29_07_2022</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/IconoCalculadora.png"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="calculadora" action="api.php" method="POST" data-operador></form>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="calculator dark">
            <div class="theme-toggler active">
                <i class="toggler-icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="display-screen">
                <div id="display"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons" name="buttons">
                <table>
                    <div name="opciones">
                        <tr>
                            <td><button class="btn-operator" id="clear" name="suprimir">C</button></td>
                            <td><button class="btn-operator" id="/" name="divicion">&divide;</button></td>
                            <td><button class="btn-operator" id="*" name="multiplicacion">&times;</button></td>
                            <td><button class="btn-operator" id="backspace" name="borrar">←</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="7">7</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="8">8</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="9">9</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" name="resta" id="-">-</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="4">4</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="5">5</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="6">6</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" name="suma" id="+">+</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="1">1</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="2">2</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="3">3</button></td>
                        <td rowspan="2"><button class="btn-equal" id="equal" name="igual">=</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="(">(</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="0">0</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id=")">)</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No necesitas php para hacer lo que quieres, a menos que tengas que procesar datos. Especifica mejor tu problema, si solo quieres dar el resultado mas personalizado lo puedes hacer desde JS, edita tu pregunta para plantear mejor tu problema, agrega un ejemplo de lo que quieres.

Comment: Hola @AntonioGalicia muchas gracias y es confusa mi pregunta, deseo dar un mensaje personalizado mediante el php que diga lo siguiente: print_r(json_encode((object) [ "Mensaje" => (string) "Realizar los operadores de la calculadora", "Servidor" => $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], "Operacion" => "el resultado de la $operador es: $res", "Resultado" => $res –